# jquery mobile ui becomes visually apparent only after window resize or chrome dev tools being opened or closed

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am working on system that is using JQuery Mobile UI and Knockout.js combination. I haven't seen anything like this, when opening 'Query window' on the page and then cancelling it - expandable list that is Jquery mobile UI `collapsible set` is being hidden and when shown again. After it is shown again knockout.js model is being refreshed

```
 if (PageObj[this.knockoutContextName]) {
     PageObj[this.knockoutContextName].valueHasMutated();
    }
```

after this expectation is that JQuery mobile UI will work but it is not being applied visually. I have checked and knockout.js viewModel has all the data present.

Even if I re-aplly `collapsibleset()` manually it still does not apply it visually (you can see it in the console window in screenshot below).

[image]

Now the weird part:
If I resize the window (without manually replying `collapsibleset()` the way I did in screenshot example above) or open or close developer tools manually it renders the expandable list properly and applies JQuery Mobile UI as if noting has happened. Bindings change too as if `collapsibleset()` would be called (Screenshot below), but this time it works.
It feels like CSS from JQuery Mobile is not being applied. What sort of mechanism gets triggered on window events that allows it to render properly that does not get triggered when I show and hide the expandable.

[image]

Comment: I can't confirm this, but I'd wager that jQM is calling `refresh` or `trigger('create')` when the window resizes (similar to an orientation change, maybe?). Try triggering refresh or create, instead of just `collapsibleSet` and seeing if that does the trick. In my experience, knockout and jQM don't play well together without lots of finagling.

Comment: @xdumaine 'knockout and jQM don't play well together' feels like huge understatement, I must say :) `trigger('create')` was second thing that I have tried after `$('#MP').collapsibleset().collapsibleset("refresh");`.None of them seems to do it. I am totally with you that it's JQM (not)doing something.